# Kivy multiple toggle buttons all read in a single function

Tags: function, kivy, save, toggle

Trying to have multiple toggle buttons on a single screen be "saved" when a button is pressed.  I am trying to take the values from the .kv into the python code to save.  Was trying to use the gender1: gender1 --- gender1.**self** to try and objectproperty in the python code, but would have to do that for every button, if that is even a solution?

.kv

```
<UserProfile>:
name: "profile"
gender1: gender1.__self__
BoxLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Gender'
        ToggleButton:
            id: gender1
            text: 'Male'
            group: 'sex'
            state: 'down'
        ToggleButton:
            id: gender2
            text: 'Female'
            group: 'sex'
        ToggleButton:
            id: gender3
            text: 'Mixed'
            group: 'sex'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Hand'
        ToggleButton:
            id: hand1
            text: 'Right'
            group: 'hand'
            state: 'down'
        ToggleButton:
            id: hand2
            text: 'Left'
            group: 'hand'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Position'
        ToggleButton:
            id: position1
            text: 'Forward'
            state: 'down'
        ToggleButton:
            id:position2
            text: 'Defense'
        ToggleButton:
            id:position3
            text: 'Goalie'
    Button:
        text: 'Submit'
        on_press: root.checkstate()
```

.py

```
class UserProfile(Screen):
def checkstate(self, **kwargs):
    buttonids = []
    for a in self.ids:
        buttonids.append(a)
    print(buttonids)
    for id in buttonids:
        print(self.{id}.state)
    # a = self.ids
    # for b in a:
    #     c = self.b.state
    #     print(c)
```

Was trying to show a couple ways I attempted...

In addition, if someone could possibly provide a decent tutorial or link to a good local storage example I'd appreciate that as well...

Comment: class Marvel(BoxLayout):

    def hulk_smash(self):
        self.ids.hulk.text = "hulk: puny god!"
        self.ids["loki"].text = "loki: >_<!!!"

how do i use the list of ids to run something like....
for a in self.ids:
    self.ids.a.state

Comment: I am trying to pull the "toggled" switches from a "profile sheet" and save those to a local storage.  then take that local storage JSON file and send it to a SQL database